# Debugging ASP.NET application on a remote IIS server

Tags: asp.net, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug an ASP.NET application for my company internal portal on a remote IIS v7 server running on a Win 2008R2 server.  The IIS server is on the same LAN as my development workstation.

The portal mostly works, however there is one function that doesn't work correctly when published to the remote server.

If I debug the application locally, using either the Visual Studio Development server or the local IISExpress server, the function works as expected, so it seems that I need to debug from the remote IIS server.

I have installed the Visual Studio 2010 Remote Debugger (msvsmon.exe, x64) on the remote server and have published my web app there.  I'm running msvsmon on the remote server as an administrator.

On my local Win7 development machine, I have the portal solution open in VS 2010 from my local hard drive, I can connect to the Remote Debugger from Visual Studio using the Tools | Attach to Process menu and I have selected the w3wp.exe at the process to attach.  The msvsmon app on the remote server shows that I have connected.

Back in Visual Studio on my local machine, I set a breakpoint on a Page_Load method (where I suspect my problem code is), however, my debug options to Start, Continue, Step Into, Step Over, etc are all disabled.

I'm apparently missing some step or concept here, but I'm at a loss as to what it is.

Comment: once attached. Goto debug-> Windows -> Modules. Right click on your DLL and load the debug symbols (.pdb) file(s). Your break point etc will then turn red.

Comment: @Kyle, I just tried that, the context menu for my .DLL has the "Load Symbols" option disabled and the Symbol Status column shows Symbols Loaded for that line.

Comment: Oh I'm unsure then. Only thing I know that can happen is if your compiled/installed dll is version A of the code and the code you are debugging with is version B the debugger will say mismatch version. I've  never heard the scenario you describe

Comment: @Kyle thank you so much! "Loading debug symbols" did the trick. It's finally working.